# Ideal Solution for Mapping system in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash, image, image-processing

I'm building image processing or mapping system kinda like google map except we have our own HD images so i'm not sure what is the best way to do this in .NET here is what im trying to do

Mapping web application build in .NET i've High resolution images , the user first load the selected area a full scaled image should be loaded 100% (original image) then he Zoom to the area he want, then he can move around this area almost like google map

1.user select area - full scaled image loaded
2.user zoom to random area - (i will receive some values for X, Y, etc.. in query string then i will extract these values and zoom/return the image based on these values)

So i'm not sure what is the ideal solution for this is it just zoom/re-size image based on the vales received from the user, or its more complicated than that?

is there any resources or samples, or any other projects done like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't yet used it, but I'd start at the Google Maps API. I understand it allows for custom tiles.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html

Khan Academy is doing this in their knowledge map: http://www.khanacademy.org/login?continue=http%3A//www.khanacademy.org/exercisedashboard (you'll have to log in to see it in action).

Comment: To clarify, I haven't used the custom tiles features yet, but I have used the API itself several times, successfully, including the JavaScript v2 and v3 and Flash versions.

Comment: This is kinda close to what i mean but now can i do the same in C# i mean do all the image processing ReZie/crop/zoom/scale/split then return the result in JaveScript along with the output images location on the server after the processing

Comment: My suggestion was that perhaps you could let the Google Maps API do all of that for you... why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @JayQuerido, I also want to build a knowledge map like Khan academy. From where should I start?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914770/creating-a-network-map-using-d3/33915156#33915156