# Creating a network map using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Does anyone know how to create a map as shown below using D3?

https://www.khanacademy.org/exercisedashboard

[image]

I am wondering how one able to zoom in/ zoom out, then give nodes some symbol plus name and clicking on the nodes leads to some URL. Is it possible this kinda map with D3?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me how can I create a knowledge map like this?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can find more information on this page;

[Examples](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery)

And it is possible.

Some useful links

http://matthiasnehlsen.com/blog/2013/05/18/using-d3js-with-play/

https://vida.io/documents/N4jSip7n68yQ48DXp

Comment: thank you for your response. Wooh! That's quite a lot of options. Now I am confused which one to use. However I saw that none of the network graphs has link associate with their nodes. Meaning when you click on the node you are redirected to some sites.